# How to disconnect from Progress database?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I've connected to the OpenEdge DB from code using `CONNECT -pf mydb.pf.`

Could anyone please tell me, How do I need to disconnect it explicitly from the code or It would be automatically disconnected from DB, If needed to disconnect via code, could I use `DISCONNECT -pf mydb.pf.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the notes at the end of the documentation for [disconnect](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920223078.html):

> By default, the AVM disconnects all databases at the end of a session.